# C# float++ e float--

Tags: c#

Eu usei o seguinte trecho de código:

```
bool plus = false;
int index = 0;

index = plus ? index++ : index--;
```

o resultado do index é 0 e não sei o porque, quando eu faço da forma abaixo funciona:

```
index += plus ? 1 : -1;
```

Alguém tem uma explicação para isso?

Comment: Parece me que o que queria fazer era `index = plus ? index+1 : index-1;` ao invés de utilizar operadores de pré e pós incremento

Comment: Complementando o que o @Isac falou: o operador de pós-decremento funciona assim: pega o valor da variável, coloca uma cópia desse valor para ser usado na operação e incrementa/decrementa a variável, mantendo a cópia intacta; então, executa a operação. No seu caso, ocorre o seguinte: (1) copia o valor de `index` (que é 0) em algo temporário (2) incrementa/decrementa `index` (que vai para +1 ou -1), mantendo sua cópia intacta (3) atribui a `index` o operando (que é 0), que no fim das contas anula o efeito colateral do operador de pós incremento/decremento

Comment: Agora eu percebi, já tinha resolvido com o segundo exemplo da pergunta, mas para testar eu usei o pré-incremento/decremento e funcionou, muito obrigado pela explicação!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**O que o operador de pós incremento faz?**

Como já explicado pelo [@Jefferson Quesado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/64969/jefferson-quesado). Quando você utiliza por exemplo `index++` você está fazendo uma chamada a uma função que irá criar uma cópia associada.

**Explicando o que aconteceu no seu código**

Como é um operador de pós incremento, você primeiro fez a atribuição da sua variável `index` e depois incrementou a cópia.

**O que você pode fazer?**

- Você pode fazer como mostrou o [@Isac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/82711/isac)

  > `index = plus ? index+1 : index-1;`
- Ou então, pode utilizar o operador de *pré incremento*. Dessa forma você estará criando e alterando o valor da cópia associada, e só depois irá fazer a atribuição.

  `index = plus ? ++index : --index;`