# Somar propriedade de objeto json

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

Tenho um objeto json e preciso multiplicar o valor `vlr_produto` com a função `add()`

```js
data={
  id: 6,
  nome_produto: "Produto",
  vlr_produto: 16.98,
  qtd: 0
}
add(data) {
  var mult = data.qtd++;
  mult * data.vlr_produto;
}
```

```html
<span (click)="add(data)">+</span>
<div>{{vlr_produto}}</div>
```

A parte de incrementar funciona normal..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código possui dois pequenos erros. Veja:

```
var mult = data.qtd++;
```

Do jeito que está, como você está usando operador de pós incremento, você está fazendo basicamente isso:

```
var mult = data.qtd;
data.qtd++;
```

Com isso o valor de `mult` fica `0` e ao fazer a multiplicação, logicamente irá retornar `0` também.

Se você não deseja alterar o valor de `data.qtd` procure fazer assim:

```
var mult = data.qtd + 1;
```

Mas se precisar mesmo alterar o valor de `data.qtd`, você pode fazer assim:

```
var mult = ++data.qtd;
```

Dessa forma você altea o valor da variável e depois com o valor atualizado você atribui ela.

E no último trecho de código da função `add()`

```
mult * data.vlr_produto
```

Você está multiplicando certo, mas não está fazendo nada além de multiplicar, o resultado da multiplicação está sendo "perdido". Já que você não está fazendo nada com ela, não está atribuindo em uma variável, não está retornando, não está imprimindo.

**OBS:** Nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/319204/c-float-e-float/319209#319209), eu explico um pouco como funciona o operador de pós e pre encremento.

Answer (score 1):

No exemplo abaixo a função add incrementa a quantidade e após multiplica pelo valor do produto. Feito, seta o valor para a propriedade total do objeto.

```js
data = {
  id: 6,
  nome_produto: "Produto",
  vlr_produto: 16.98,
  qtd: 0,
  total: 0
};

add(data) {
   data.total = data.vlr_produto * (++data.qtd)
}
```

```html
<span (click)="add(data)">+</span>
<div>{{total}}</div>
```